# Multilevel sorting of an array of strings based on some conditions

Tags: java, arrays, string, sorting

An array of strings is given as an input. 
Each string is of the following format:

{first name}{a space character}{a roman numeral}

The array has to be sorted first based on the name and if name is same, then on the basis of roman numeral.

e.g.

Input - ["Philip IV", "Philip II", "John X"]

Output - ["John X", "Philip II", "Philip IV"]

**Another variation:**
The array of strings contains some duplicates. The array has to be sorted based on the number of occurrences of a string in decreasing order and if number of occurrences are same for any two or more strings then sort them based on their reverse lexicographic order.

e.g.

Input - ["abc", "abc", "xyz", "xyz", "pqr", "pqr", "pqr"]

Output - ["pqr", "xyz", "abc"]

This question has come quite a few times in interviews with some variations here and there. Both are related to multilevel sorting.

I could come up only with a brute force approach.

For the first one, create an ordering mapping for roman numerals and use it to implement a comparator which will handle first name and then roman numerals.

For the second one, create a map of strings and their occurrences and use it to implement a comparator.

Is there a better way to approach such problems? Any help would be highly appreciated.

Comment: what you have done so far?

Comment: If I understand your description of what you have tried, it does indeed look like the adequate solution. One may fiddle over details such as time complexity (i.e. data types used mostly with regards to Java collections) and other performance-related aspects (multi-threaded initialization of your roman numeral converter or occurrence mapping, etc.) but I can't really see another easy solution with just the Java framework itself.

Comment: Also, +1 for the question, but voting to close as "too broad".

Comment: What do you mean with "a brute force approach"? Ordering with Collections and Comparator uses a optimized merge sort algorithm based on divide & conquer. It's probably the fastest and stable way to proceed. Look at the Oracle docs https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/collections/algorithms/

Comment: @JohnnyWiller: I've tried the approaches mentioned above. Just wanted to know if it's possible to do it in a better way.

Comment: @MarcoA.Hernandez By brute force, I meant the first straight forward solution which came to my mind, without thinking much about complexities. Well I agree with "Ordering with Collections and Comparator uses a optimized merge sort algorithm based on divide & conquer", I just wanted to be sure that at application level can we do something better or not?

Answer (score 0):

it can be solved by sorting the names at first and then the roman counting.

[image]

This approach will work only if you use one of the stable sorting technique otherwise it will mess up the first column when you sort the second one.